# How do determine MOSFET parameters in LTSPICE

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, integrated-circuit, ltspice

I am designing a phase locked loop on LTspice (which I'm new to), but have come across a snag in the procedure:

- Is there a way to determine the output resistance of a mosfet (as the I'm not able to determine the early voltage or lambda from the model file)?
- How does one separate the gain and the phase plot on performing AC analysis?
- Finally, how to determine the varying \$g_m\$ (transconductance) that is induced by the body effect whilst performing DC analysis?.

Comment: Why would you need to know Rds for a MOSFET in a PLL? If you need it for the phase detector, it usually doesn't influence enough the calculations, since you'd be working with pulses. And why mention [tag:ltspice] if the only connection is the fact that you want to use it (and nothing else)? (edit) ...and I just realized the timestamp. I only saw the answer timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

To determine a parameter from simulation you start with the fundamental definition for that parameter. For the output impedance we have rds==Del(Vds)/Del(Ids)|Vgs=constant. Set up your simulation at the DC conditions on the circuit-- VGS and VDS. In series with VDS insert an ac generator, vds, and monitor Del(Ids)=ids, the small signal response. Now the ratio of the small signal response to the small signal excitation, gds=ids/vds, the reciprocal of this is rds.
For gm use its definition: gm=ids/vgs|vds=0; gmb=ids/vbs|vds=0,vgs=0 where vbs is the body to source small signal potential.
Magnitude and phase are found using calculator functions if not directly enabled in your plotting tool.